# Number of active IDs in each period

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
ID |   START  |   END
1  |2016-12-31|2017-02-30
2  |2017-01-30|2017-10-30
3  |2016-12-21|2018-12-30
```

I want to know the number of active IDs in each possible day. So basically count the number of overlapping time periods.

What I did to calculate this was creating a new data frame **c_df** with the **columns** date and **count**. The first column was populated using a range:

```
all_dates = pd.date_range(start=min(df['START']), end=max(df['END']))
```

Then for every line in my original data frame I calculated a different range for the start and end dates:

```
id_dates = pd.date_range(start=min(user['START']), end=max(user['END']))
```

I then used this range of dates to increment by one the corresponding count cell in **c_df**.

All these loops though are not very efficient for big data sets and look ugly. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: You got an error: `2017-02-30` is not a valid date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dataframe is small enough so that performance is not a concern, create a date range for each row, then explode them and count how many times each date exists in the exploded series.

Requires pandas >= 0.25:

```
df.apply(lambda row: pd.date_range(row['START'], row['END']), axis=1) \
    .explode() \
    .value_counts() \
    .sort_index()
```

---

If your dataframe is large, take advantage of numpy broadcasting to improve performance.

Work with any version of pandas:

```
dates = pd.date_range(df['START'].min(), df['END'].max()).values
start = df['START'].values[:, None]
end = df['END'].values[:, None]

mask = (start <= dates) & (dates <= end)
result = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': dates,
    'Count': mask.sum(axis=0)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Create `IntervalIndex` and use genex or list comprehension with `contains` to check each date again each interval (Note: I made a smaller sample to test on this solution)

```
Sample `df`

Out[56]:
   ID      START        END
0   1 2016-12-31 2017-01-20
1   2 2017-01-20 2017-01-30
2   3 2016-12-28 2017-02-03
3   4 2017-01-20 2017-01-25

iix = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df.START, df.END, closed='both')
all_dates = pd.date_range(start=min(df['START']), end=max(df['END']))

df_final = pd.DataFrame({'dates': all_dates, 
                         'date_counts': (iix.contains(dt).sum() for dt in all_dates)})

In [58]: df_final
Out[58]:
        dates  date_counts
0  2016-12-28            1
1  2016-12-29            1
2  2016-12-30            1
3  2016-12-31            2
4  2017-01-01            2
5  2017-01-02            2
6  2017-01-03            2
7  2017-01-04            2
8  2017-01-05            2
9  2017-01-06            2
10 2017-01-07            2
11 2017-01-08            2
12 2017-01-09            2
13 2017-01-10            2
14 2017-01-11            2
15 2017-01-12            2
16 2017-01-13            2
17 2017-01-14            2
18 2017-01-15            2
19 2017-01-16            2
20 2017-01-17            2
21 2017-01-18            2
22 2017-01-19            2
23 2017-01-20            4
24 2017-01-21            3
25 2017-01-22            3
26 2017-01-23            3
27 2017-01-24            3
28 2017-01-25            3
29 2017-01-26            2
30 2017-01-27            2
31 2017-01-28            2
32 2017-01-29            2
33 2017-01-30            2
34 2017-01-31            1
35 2017-02-01            1
36 2017-02-02            1
37 2017-02-03            1
```